# UNLINK OR RELINK - Google assistant account linking flow

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, assistant

I am developing a custom action for google assistant.
In order to get user data and other user info. I need allow account linking flow.

My Account Linking flow:

1. Open the Google Assistant app on Android or iPhone.
2. Say the Action – "Talk to My test app”
3. Read and agree to the Action Terms and Conditions that appear on the screen.
4. Sign in with Web app.
5. Go back to Google assistant and ends linking flow

Everything works properly. But once account linked, I am not able to test the flow again

Could anyone suggest, how to unlink my account and test the above account linking process again? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During development you can unlink your account via the actions on google [console](https://console.actions.google.com/). If you navigate to the test window, you can see a settings button on the top right, click that and a setting pop-up should open. There you should look for an unlink button.

[image]

This will unlink your account, so when you restart the conversation for your action with this account, you will be prompted to sign-in again via accountlinking. This also works if you are testing on your phone. You just need to make sure that the account on your phone and the simulator are the same.